# Handling Exceptions without try-catch

Tags: java

Suppose we have a method (not main) and it has this piece of code in it's body:

```
if (a > b) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Fail!");
}
```

Is it equivalent to try-catch way of handling an exception or including the throws in the signature?

Comment: Are you asking if the code is equivalent to a `try`-`catch`?

Comment: That is not handling any exception, that is creating a new one and throwing it.  The caller then has to deal with that exception.

Comment: So, in a way, it's just like throwing exception in the function method, right?

Comment: I think you need to read up on the basics of Exceptions... I am not seeing a clear question here, and I get the feeling that you don't even know what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 kinds of exceptions in Java: checked exceptions and unchecked exceptions.

When a checked exception is thrown, the method signature must add a throw declaration. The calling code should embrace it in a try-catch.

When an unchecked exception is thrown, the method signature should not add the throw declaration. The calling code is not obliged to embrace it in a try-catch.

How to distinguish between these two kinds of exceptions? An unchecked exception does extend RuntimeException.

IllegalArgumentException belongs to the unchecked exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

If you throw a Exception you need to catch it or you need to add throws to the method.

But I think you are confused as that is a RuntimeException you are throwing. RuntimeException need not be handled by try catch blocks. So it is not = to having a try catch as it doesn't need one...

So you are really asking the difference between a checked vs unchecked exception.

Comment: So, instead of just ignoring the runtime exception, we are making it display message here.Is it?

Comment: You can catch a runtime exception to display a message. You can catch it as try { }catch(RuntimeExeption e) { } or with Exception e since Exception is its superclass

Answer (score 0):

It's better to include a try catch and handle what you are going to do when that exception comes up.

But the way you have it written, it'll just cascade up until it comes across a try-catch or something that takes care of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

This is nowhere equivalent to try-catch handling or throws.

Here, your method is throwing an `IllegalArgumentException`, which has to be handled in the method definition with throws as `throws IllegalArgumentException` or the caller of this particular method has to use try-catch to handle the IllegalArgumentException thrown by this method.